# Make summary reports of all items in a list and send the summary in an e-mail

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

Out of all the items in a list, I need a summary about them weekly in an e-mail. I cannot have individual notifications being sent each time one item changes, or gets created. The goal is to create reports from the aggregated data in all items by the user(s) in a list.

Tried: Collect data from user action; send e-mail.

We do no have access to central administration of the site.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here this can be achieved by below options:

- A custom event receiver can be developed and whenever the changes
  been made to the list items it can be written to a file which will be
  having all the actions been done on the list items for the whole
  week.

  We can develop a custom timer job or scheduler which will run weekly
  to read this file to send the report as part of a mail.

Answer (score 0):

To fulfil your requirement you could use build in 'Alerts' set up a weekly summary on list/library with new/modified items.